# Elasticsearch: why does the id suddenly start with AV?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a list of records from Elasticsearch and noticed a different ID pattern.

**Old IDs**:

```
49578465121306643679991964388767927303403148324105007342.0
```

**New IDs**:

```
AV-cjKUxTlDOLeISlddS
```

Unfortunately, nobody knows what was changed that could have caused the new pattern. To avoid a conflict in the future, I'd like to know what's going on.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were old and new ids generated from the same version of elastic? Did you stop providing Ids to newly indexed fields? The new IDs look like an automatically generated hash when no ID was provided. I'm not sure about legacy elastic ID formats, but the old ids look like they were supplied during indexing

Comment: @Miek Looks like you're right. Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Alright, added it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were old and new ids generated from the same version of elastic? Did you stop providing Ids to newly indexed fields? The new IDs look like an automatically generated hash when no ID was provided. I'm not sure about legacy elastic ID formats, but the old ids look like they were supplied during indexing